# Ubuntu is not booting after installing windows 8 in same machine?

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

In my machine i installed ubuntu 11 os first in /dev/sda2 (D drive) and then I installed Windows8 in C drive.After installation I am not able to see ubuntu in the multi os menu though space is reserved.

I guess the boot loader is corrupt.Any Suggestion on this will help

Comment: Here is the link of Rescatux: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/
Burn a CD or create a USB key with Unetbootin and it will help you fix the boot problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a Ubuntu LiveCd / USB and follow this guide:

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/how-to-recover-grub2-linux.html